# Quantum gates with respect to phase angles

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

We can say that

$X (\cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle + e^{i \phi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle) = \cos \frac{\pi-\theta}{2} |0\rangle + e^{-i \phi}\sin \frac{\pi-\theta}{2} |1\rangle$,

a fact that can be derived by multiplying the $X$ matrix and the state vector and using angle identities:

$X (\cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle + e^{i \phi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle) = e^{i \phi}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle + \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |1\rangle = e^{i \phi}\cos \frac{\pi - \theta}{2} |0\rangle + \sin \frac{\pi - \theta}{2} |1\rangle = \cos \frac{\pi-\theta}{2} |0\rangle + e^{-i \phi}\sin \frac{\pi-\theta}{2} |1\rangle$

Is there a writeup somewhere or a standard way to derive this identity for other gates, i.e. $Y, Z, H, \sqrt{Y}$?

Comment: Do you know about the Bloch sphere? Any unitary gate acting on a qubit is equivalent to a rotation of the Bloch vector (describing the state) about some axis by some angle (axis and angle determined by the unitary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quantum Mechanic said in the comments, the Bloch vector is the way to go. Any one-qubit pure state $|\psi\rangle$ can be written in the form
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\frac12(I+n_XX+n_YY+n_ZZ)
$$
where $n_X^2+n_Y^2+n_Z^2=1$. Moreover, the vector $\vec{n}=(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)$ can also be written as $(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$. So, if we can tell what happens to the Bloch vector, you can easily map this through to the angles.

So, consider the action of the $X$ matrix of $|\psi\rangle$.
$$
|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\mapsto X|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X=\frac12(I+n_XX-n_YY-n_ZZ).
$$
You just need to use the commutation properties of the Pauli matrices. So, we see that
$$
(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)\xrightarrow X (n_X,-n_Y,-n_Z)
$$

By the same token, you very quickly get
\begin{align*}
(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)&\xrightarrow Z (-n_X,-n_Y,n_Z) \\
(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)&\xrightarrow H (n_Z,-n_Y,n_X)
\end{align*}
I've left the other couple for you to do.